# Prove: If $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally, then $\sum a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence is $1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Prove: If $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally, then $\sum a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence  is $1$.

How should I approach this? I tried looking at $\sum |a_n z^n|$ to conclude about $|z|$.

Comment: $\sum a_n$ converges implies $a_n \to 0$ implies $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \le 1$.  $\sum |a_n|$ diverges implies $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \ge 1$ by the contrapositive of the root test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is the radius of converge of a power series, then that series converges absolutely for all $z$ with $|z| < r$, and diverges for  $|z| > r$.  So conditional convergence tells you exactly what the radius is.

Comment: $\sum a_n$ converges so $\sum a_n z^n\rightarrow |z|\geq 1$

$\sum |a_n|$ diverges so $\sum|a_n|| z|^n\rightarrow |z|\leq 1$

so $|z|=1$?

Comment: What you wrote didn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

This follows from *Abel's lemma*:

> If $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$ is a power series and if the sequence $(|a_n|s^n)$ is bounded then $f$ converges absolutely in $B(0,s)$.

Indeed,
if $0<t<s$ then $q=t/s <1$ and $|a_n|t^n \leqslant M q^n$ where $M$ is the bound we're assuming exists, so 
$$\sum |a_n|t^n \leqslant M \frac{1}{1-q}<\infty$$

On to your problem, the sequence $(|a_n|)$ is certainly bounded since it converges to $0$ by virtue of the conditional convergence, so Abel's lemma guarantees $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$ converges absolutely in $B(0,1)$. This means the radius is at least $1$.

It cannot have radius of convergence larger than $1$, because by Abel's lemma, again, it would force *absolute convergence* on $B(0,r)$ with $r>1$, contrary to your hypothesis.